# "He was tearing the curtain" x "He was tearing off the curtain"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What's the difference between these two terms? I tried to find out by myself and got to the conclusion that "tearing off the curtain" means removing the curtain from the wall, an "tearing the curtain" without preposition, means damaging the curtain, is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

> tearing the curtain
>   tearing *up* the curtain

is to **rip** the curtain by splitting it into pieces by hand.

> tearing *off* the curtain from the wall
>   tearing *off* the curtain from the window

is to **separate** the curtain *from somewhere*, a prepositional phrase is usually added for context.

> She *tore off* the coupon from the circular.

whereas

> tearing *down* the curtain from the wall
>   tearing *down* the curtain from the window

is to **pull down** the curtain *from somewhere*, a prepositional phrase is usually added for context.

Your full sentences might be

> He was **tearing** the curtain *into little pieces*.
>   He was **tearing off** the curtain *from the wall*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you are right.The verb *tear off* means *to quickly remove*

> She tore off her apron and ran into the living room.

*To tear* means *to pull* or *to be pulled apart*,or *to pull pieces off*

> The dog tore her dress.